# How to execute sh file from rest service on linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, rest, process

I have a rest service written in java on linux machine.

I'm using:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmmnd);
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmmnd).inheritIO();
p = pb.start();

p.waitFor();
```

I can execute commands like `mkdir`, `touch` ...
But when i try to run sh file nothing happens (for example: `sudo sh /home/mydir/myfile.sh`)

Is it a permission issue? How can I resolve that?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a bad idea.  I would strongly advise against it.  This is not what REST services are for.

Comment: I am totally disagree with this kind of solution. Rest services are not planned to do that. Java is a platform independent language but that code will only run on Linux. Anyway, check the execute (X) permission on yopur file: chmod +X myfile.sh.

Comment: thanks, i have 777 on that file.

Comment: i want this service to start or stop another service

Comment: Is your script run at all? add a line at the very beginning of your script to create a file (give an absolute path so you know where to look for it), and check if the file is created or not?  Also if this is in a try/catch can you make sure that the Exception is printed if it is caught?

Comment: for testing i did use touch/mkdir - it did not work, and i got no error. i've tried getting a message from input/output/error streams - got nothing :(

Comment: Why do you have to use `sudo`? That sounds like a code smell. Can your Java program itself simply run with the correct permissions? (Also: if you want a URL to invoke a command-line program, there's already a standard for that. It's called Common Gateway Interface or CGI and it was invented in the early 1990s.)

Answer (score 0):

Only file execution permission is not suffice here. First run the command `sudo sh /home/mydir/myfile.sh` from command prompt manually and check whether work or not? Is you `sodo` ask for a password? Is your web service account from where you are executing the command has permission to execute as `sudo`? Also check whether your web application has file access permission to location (means can it execute `cd /home/mydir/`) `/home/mydir/myfile.sh` or not?

Also in your code read the output and check what is the actual error?

```
p.getOutputStream();
```

Also try with:-

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo sh /home/mydir/myfile.sh");
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("/new_path/out.txt"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes sudo sh /home/mydir/myfile.sh runs OK, and i can run sudo commnad from my service, and my service has access to the file locatrion. only when executing the sh (sudo sh...) i get nothing. i tried getting the output/input/error stream - i got no message

Comment: What happened  while you run `sudo sh /home/mydir/myfile.sh ` in command prompt? Also as I mentioned in my answer `p.getOutputStream();` Print the out put in your application.